# Why the address of entry point doesn't match NT header?

Tags: c++, windows, operating-system, loader

I want to find out the entry of a windows program. as far as [MS documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms809762(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) describes "ImageBase":

> When the linker creates an executable, it assumes that the file will
> be memory-mapped to a specific location in memory. ...

I use dumpbin to show ImageBase in PE header, to find where to map:

```
>dumpbin /HEADERS my.exe
...
            13D0 entry point (00000001400013D0) mainCRTStartup
            1000 base of code
       140000000 image base (0000000140000000 to 0000000140006FFF)
...
```

So that entry function `mainCRTStartup` is mapped to virtual address `0x00000001400013D0` , but when I run the program and print address:

```
with __ImageBase = 0x7ff771e60000
with mainCRTStartup = 0x7ff771e61390
```

**that address printed by program seems to be at the bottom of user space (near windows dlls), far away from "image base + entry point". Why is that?**

I also tried to examine memory at `0x00000001400013D0` , and there seems to be no mapped pages.

here is the source (build by vs2019, x64):

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

extern "C" const IMAGE_DOS_HEADER __ImageBase;
extern "C" int mainCRTStartup();

int main() {
    printf("with __ImageBase = 0x%llx\r\n", (HINSTANCE)&__ImageBase);
    printf("with mainCRTStartup = 0x%llx\r\n", mainCRTStartup);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "*far away from "image base + entry point"*" - it is hardly far away. It is only 64 bytes (`0x7ff771e61390-0x7ff771e60000=0x1390`, `0x13D0-0x1390=0x40=64`) away from where you are expecting it to be. `0x140000000` is merely a *preferred* load address, whereas `0x7ff771e60000` is the *actual* load address in your case.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau  In that case, is there a way for me to find out where windows loader will actually load it? btw I have read some dump tools, which will read memory from ```0x140000000```, so I think that address may make some use.

Comment: @H3d9: Modern windows intentionally randomizes address spaces (ASLR).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using a recent version of Visual Studio your application is probably opted-in to ASLR (Address Space Layout Randomization) by default. This is a security feature that is designed to make it harder for shell code (exploits) to find places to latch on to.

Try adding the [`/FIXED`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/fixed-fixed-base-address?view=msvc-160) linker switch, this will prevent your .EXE from having relocation information and in turn prevents ASLR from relocating your PE in memory. `/DYNAMICBASE:NO` is a weaker version of `/FIXED` that you can also try, especially for .DLLs.